# ImageMagick resize by percentage and limit

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize various images using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/).

I have a requirement for this to be done in a single command without any supporting extra language.

I want to resize all images below a certain width to 115% (or the equivalent: resize all images to a certain size while restricting the maximum enlargement to 115% of the original).

I've tried mixing the [different options](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Is this even possible?

---

### Update:

I used the `distort` operator as a possible solution:

```
convert in.jpg +distort srt "%[fx:(w<1600)?1.15:1] 0" out.jpg
```

but when distorting the images >1600 pixels it still does an operation and rewrites the image with a slightly different pixel count.

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier just to use the existing system's commands along with `convert` to evaluate the high-level logic.

Example, I'll leverage [test](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) utility

```bash
test $(identify -format "%[fx:(w<1600)?1:0]" in.jpg) -eq 1 && \
     convert in.jpg -resize 115% out.jpg
```

In [ImageMagick 7](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php), the option `-exit` will be introduced, so it would be possible to terminate an ImageMagick command if a condition is not meet.

**Update**

[Affine distortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/affine/#affine) may be a better approach. As the following affine matrix will not alter the image

```
| 1 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 |
| 0 0 1 |
```

But the following will resize by 115%

```
| 1.15 0    0 |
| 0    1.15 0 |
| 0    0    1 |
```

```sh
convert in.jpg +distort AffineProjection \
        '%[fx:(w<1600)?1.15:1],0,0,%[fx:(w<1600)?1.15:1],0,0' \
        +repage out3.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly adding system command is not an option. I will try the affine distortion though.